# How can I run these commands against each User profile?

Tags: powershell

I aim to create a script to create various files on a system profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$profilelist` is a string, so you probably don't want to iterate it. To get all `ProfileImagePath` properties you can use the following:

```bsh
$allProfiles = @((dir $profilelist | Get-ItemProperty).profileImagePath | Where-Object { $_ -notlike 'C:\Windows*' })
```

This will output:

```
C:\Users\user1
C:\Users\user2
```

and so on. `@( ... )` is to make sure you get an array even if there's only one matching profile.

Note that I excluded default Windows profiles as you probably don't want them anyway. Remember to change `$profilelist` to `$allProfiles` in `ForEach`.